# Script on IIS server won't load xml from server on same machine

Tags: jquery, xml, iis

At work I have a machine that spits out machine data in XML on port 5000.
On the same machine runs a IIS server with the script below.
If I run the script on the machines browser it works fine, but when I try to run the script from a computer on the same network it won't return the XML feed.
DevTools returns with "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"
I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Machine Monitor</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
          $('#demo').load("http://localhost:5000/current?path=//*[@id=%22d2_avail%22]");
      });
      
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy Things like this might help.

Comment: @LexLi I don't get any CORS errors. Disabled the firewall but still no luck

Comment: Do you get the same error in other browsers? It might help to understand if this is a browser side or server side issue.